# Java - A simple (to everyone but me) method - Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

Ok, so I hope you can all help, I have been tasked whilst tying to learn the language with the age-old test of simple savings account and checking account using inheritence.

My problem is, I want to make the checking account incapable of going over its overdraft limit and the savings account incapable of going below 0 but cant work out how? my code so far is as follows:

**SUPERCLASS (BankAccount):**

```
public class BankAccount
    {
        protected String CustomerName;
        protected String AccountNumber;
        protected float Balance;


//Constructor Methods

 public BankAccount(String CustomerNameIn, String AccountNumberIn, float BalanceIn)
        {
            CustomerName = CustomerNameIn;
            AccountNumber = AccountNumberIn;
            Balance = BalanceIn;

        }

      // Get  name
      public String getCustomerName()
        {
            return (CustomerName);
        }

      // Get account number
      public String getAccountNumber()
        {
            return (AccountNumber);
        }

       public float getBalance()
        {
            return (Balance);
        }


        public void Withdraw(float WithdrawAmountIn)
       {  
           if(WithdrawAmountIn < 0)
                System.out.println("Sorry, you can not withdraw a negative amount, if you wish to withdraw money please use the withdraw method");
           else
                Balance = Balance - WithdrawAmountIn;
       }

        public void Deposit(float DepositAmountIn)
       {
           if(DepositAmountIn < 0)
                System.out.println("Sorry, you can not deposit a negative amount, if you wish to withdraw money please use the withdraw method");
           else 
           Balance = Balance + DepositAmountIn;
       }


    } // End Class BankDetails
```

**SUBCLASS (SavingsAccount):**

```
public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount
  {   

      private float Interest;

      public SavingsAccount(String CustomerNameIn, String AccountNumberIn, float InterestIn, float BalanceIn)
        {
            super (CustomerNameIn, AccountNumberIn, BalanceIn);
            Interest = InterestIn;
        }


      public float getInterestAmount()
       {
           return (Interest);
       }

      public float newBalanceWithInterest()
       {  
           Balance = (getBalance() + (getBalance()  * Interest / 100) );

           return (Balance);
       }

       public void SavingsOverdraft()
       {
            if( Balance < 0)
                System.out.println("Sorry, this account is not permitted to have an overdraft facility");
       }

   }
```

**SUBCLASS (CheckingAccount):**

```
public class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount
  {
      private float Overdraft;


      public CheckingAccount(String CustomerNameIn, String AccountNumberIn, float BalanceIn, float OverdraftIn)
        {

            super (CustomerNameIn, AccountNumberIn, BalanceIn);

            Overdraft = OverdraftIn;
        }

       public float getOverdraftAmount()
       {
           return(Overdraft);
       }

      public void setOverdraft()
        {
            if (Balance < Overdraft)
                System.out.println("Sorry, the overdraft facility on this account cannot exceed £100");

       }
    }
```

Thank you very very much for any advice and help!

Comment: A tip while you're learning Java: learn and use the coding style conventions. For example, method and variable names don't start with a lowercase letter. So your **SavingsOverdraft()** method should be **savingsOverdraft()**, attribute **Balance** should be **balance**, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add getOverdraftAmount() to your base class:

```
public int getOverdraftAmount() {
    return 0;
}
```

Then override that method in account subclasses that allow overdrafts. Then revise your logic for withdrawal to take into account that the overdraft limit might not be zero.

```
public void Withdraw(float WithdrawAmountIn)
   {  
       if(WithdrawAmountIn < 0)
            System.out.println("Sorry, you can not withdraw a negative amount, if you wish to withdraw money please use the withdraw method");
       else if (Balance - WithdrawAmountIn < -getOverdraftAmount()) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, this withdrawal would exceed the overdraft limit");
       else 
            Balance = Balance - WithdrawAmountIn;
   }
```

Comment: One problem that I forgot to mention sorry, Savings has no overdraft allowance so cannot go lower than 0 yet checking account can go to -100!

Comment: Right. So if the savings account has an overdraft limit of 0, and the checking account has a limit of 100, then they can both use the same logic. A limit of 0 is the same as no overdraft capability.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you will need to override the withdraw function in both the subclasses in order to change the functionality of each individually.

**SUBCLASS (SavingsAccount):**

```
public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount
  {   

      private float Interest;

      public SavingsAccount(String CustomerNameIn, String AccountNumberIn, float InterestIn, float BalanceIn)
        {
            super (CustomerNameIn, AccountNumberIn, BalanceIn);
            Interest = InterestIn;
        }


      public float getInterestAmount()
       {
           return (Interest);
       }

      public float newBalanceWithInterest()
       {  
           Balance = (getBalance() + (getBalance()  * Interest / 100) );

           return (Balance);
       }

       public void SavingsOverdraft()
       {
            if( Balance < 0)
                System.out.println("Sorry, this account is not permitted to have an overdraft facility");
       }

       public void Withdraw(float WithdrawAmountIn)
       {  
           if(WithdrawAmountIn < 0)
                System.out.println("Sorry, you can not withdraw a negative amount, if you wish to withdraw money please use the withdraw method");
           else if (WithdrawAmountIn>Balance)
                System.out.println("Sorry, you don't have this much in your account.");
           else
                Balance = Balance - WithdrawAmountIn;
       }

   }
```

**SUBCLASS (CheckingAccount):**

```
public class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount
  {
      private float Overdraft;


      public CheckingAccount(String CustomerNameIn, String AccountNumberIn, float BalanceIn, float OverdraftIn)
        {

            super (CustomerNameIn, AccountNumberIn, BalanceIn);

            Overdraft = OverdraftIn;
        }

       public float getOverdraftAmount()
       {
           return(Overdraft);
       }

      public void setOverdraft()
        {
            if (Balance < Overdraft)
                System.out.println("Sorry, the overdraft facility on this account cannot exceed £100");

       }
        public void Withdraw(float WithdrawAmountIn)
       {  
           if(WithdrawAmountIn < 0)
                System.out.println("Sorry, you can not withdraw a negative amount, if you wish to withdraw money please use the withdraw method");
           else if (Balance-WithdrawAmountIn<getOverdraftAmount()
                System.out.println("Sorry, you cannot withdraw this much");
           else
                Balance = Balance - WithdrawAmountIn;
       }
    }
```